# VPN router configuration

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I've set up an IPSec VPN tunnel and connected it. It works fine.

Now, I want to access the remote subnet. How do I do it? How do I "connect" my machine to this VPN?

My local secure group is `192.168.1.0/24` and the remote secure group is `192.168.2.0/24`.

How can I make my notebook (an Ubuntu 14.04) access some `192.168.2.3` for example?

I couldn't find information about it. Maybe it is obvious, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: what exactly happens when you try?  It should be able to automatically, as long as the routes are setup by the VPN client.  If not, you may have to setup the route(s) yourself.

Comment: I don't know. Looks like it is not connected at all. I need a VPN client in my machine to access this VPN? I didn't found good docs about it.

Comment: Yes, the notebook running Ubuntu will need to act as a client to the VPN you setup and complete the tunnel. At the point routes will be added to it that allow access to the new network.